# How to revert a merge commit?

Tags: git

I accidentally merged my branch to master. Since then several commits has been pushed by other team members. How can I revert just the commit I merged accidentally.

git log:
commit 5
commit 4
commit 3
commit 2(Accidental Merge branch )
commit 1

How to revert commit 2? 
I tried the command
git revert

I get an error `error: commit 9576fbad0f1dd6f09412d9c87411e3c79fc6c961 is a merge but no -m option was given.`

Comment: Consider rebasing, removing the mistaken commit.

Comment: How to rebase, so I can remove the changes made in commit 2 and commit 3, but still have commit 4 and commit 5?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/648281/remove-a-merge-commit-in-git may help?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
git revert 9576fbad0f1dd6f09412d9c87411e3c79fc6c961 -m 1
```

and don't forget to `push` you changes after that.

[Read more](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Comment: I read about it. The merge has 2 parents, hence the confusion. I tried to revert to the commit to the second commit number in the merge, nothing got reverted:

Comment: us186007@MUSUS186007-791 ~/Projects/jmeter ±fix_merge_mess⚡ » git revert -m 2 9576fbad0f1dd6f09412d9c87411e3c79fc6c961                                      141 ↵
On branch fix_merge_mess
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/fix_merge_mess'.

Comment: use `git log` to observe logs. don't forget to `git push origin master`